# Integrating new styles/pages to an existing codebase

Tags: sass, styles, stylesheet

I am working on re-doing a WordPress website which already has globally defined style rules for example:

```
h1 { font-size:30px }
```

I have to add in a new page at a time while maintaining the existing style rules for the website. So what I have done is defined a new 'namespace' with a class in `Sass` like `.certainPage{...}` and am nesting all the styles underneath it. Now I can just give whatever element the class `certainPage` and add the new styles, while ensuring that the remainder of the site remains as it was.

This is obviously leading to a fairly messy stylesheet, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this for now? Keep in mind that I have to be adding a page at a time.

Comment: Is the original stylesheet a comprehensive theme?  Is it also in Sass?

Comment: It is also Sass that I'll be manipulating.

Comment: This is really an opinion question, but... your approach seems ok, but maybe consider using the namespace woven in (assuming this is not a theme, which I wouldn't mess with) using `.myNameSpace &` syntax where appropriate.  Doesn't have to be an either/or approach.